# Web login from Android app using Qr code scanner

Tags: android, authentication, qr-code, whatsapp

I want to implement QR code scanner login in my app. In my case, I have a web portal and have an Android application for this web portal. The users can scan the QR code from the web through my Android app and after completing the verification process, the user can log in to the web portal (the same process as in WhatsApp).

https://galois.com/blog/2011/01/quick-authentication-using-mobile-devices-and-qr-codes/

Comment: I'm looking into this myself, I think the way to go would be to have the web app generate the qr code and save it to your backend (like firebase or whatever you're using), after that the mobile app would scan the qr code and you'd match the web client that generated the qr code with the user account that's logged on in the mobile app, giving the web client temporary access to the account.